# Not have anything as title

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible not to have anything as the title and subtitle?

I wish for that space to be deleted from the HTML code also.
I have done a screenshot image below that explains better, I hope...:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am with the Cognito Application Support team and to answer your question yes you can hide the title of the form if the form is embedded on a website (which in your case I believe it is).

This feature is discussed on our help site here:

https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/166/style--publish/customizing-form-styles

The "Hide logo & title when embedded in your site" option would seen by clicking on the Publish Tab for your form, on the left side of the screen choose the "Form Styles" Tab and you should see it just above the Text Color options.

[image]

Hopefully that will do just what you were asking.